How to add child element after checking if child with specific value already exists in JS/JQuery?
So I've been trying to figure out, how to append a div element to an existing div element, after checking if the child div element contains a specific text or not in JS/JQuery.
My HTML:
<div id="mii">
</div>

My JQuery:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mii").click(function() {
        if($("#mii div span:contains('foo')") == false) {
            $("#mii").append("<div class='mii-item'><span>foo</span></div>");
        }
    });
});

My CSS (Not rly relevant tho):
#mii {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
#mii:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mii-item {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}

I can't understand why it doesn't work, even though I debugged it and tried various things, so any help is welcomed!
Link to JSFiddle

even though I debugged it - don't forget to debug $("#mii div span:contains('foo')")

JQuery selector will return a array like of DOM element.
See the output by console.log($("#mii div span:contains('foo')")).
So you need to check the length of array if it contains matched elements.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mii").click(function() {
        if($("#mii div span:contains('foo')").length === 0) {
            $("#mii").append("<div class='mii-item'><span>foo</span></div>");
        }
    });
});

